# Is it possible to Search User in Azure AD using partial Email address

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to search a user in Azure AD based on Email Address partial search? 
I want to search "rocketsingh@gmail.com" just by entering singh.

I don't think graph api allows a partial search on email. If it is possible, then let us know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it does not allow to search with partial or free text search with [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)